# Hide in taskbar via a checkbox

Tags: c#

Just wondering how I could hide my application from the taskbar via a checkbox.

this.ShowInTaskbar closes my application so I'm just wondering what the best way to achieve this is?

Comment: So, the framework you are using is rather important to your question.  Using a windows form, it works 100% for me.  You do see a blink when toggling the state but it does not close the application.  In my `checkBoxBob_CheckedChanged` event, I have added one line.. `this.ShowInTaskbar = checkBoxBob.Checked;` .. as I said, it works fine but there is a blink.

Comment: Even with default framework I still have no luck, I appreciate your response and overall help though.

Comment: There is no "default framework".  You are using WPF, Winforms, or something else.  Let's help you through this :)  DONT GIVE UP!!!

Comment: Yeah! Default winforms, my bad. I don't know why mine would be crashing, I'm gonna try in a new project and see what happens.